# Javascript Open New Window with Tabs

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript webpage that opens new windows just fine. But the customer brought to my attention that the new window '*doesn't look right*' because is missing the tabs

[image]

They want it to look like this, which is '*normal*' behavior when you open a new window on a HTML page
[image]

I don't see any options on the window.open method to force show the new window with tabs. I did notice that if i right click on the new window it gives me an option show the tabs and that changes the way the new window looks to the '*normal*' way.

[image]

Any ideas?

Here is my code

```
if (!isCtrlClick && !isShiftClick && !description) {
    this.$router.push({name:'ItemDetails', params: { sid: id, source: this.source }});
} else if (isShiftClick) {
    const itemDetailsData = this.$router.resolve({name:'ItemDetails', params: { sid: id, source: this.source }});
    window.open(itemDetailsData.href, "_blank","resizable=1");
} else if (isCtrlClick){
    const itemDetailsData = this.$router.resolve({name:'ItemDetails', params: { sid: id, source: this.source }});
    var keepFocus = window.open(itemDetailsData.href, "_blank");
    keepFocus.blur();
    window.focus();
    // context menu
} else if (description == 'newPage') {
    const itemDetailsData = this.$router.resolve({name:'ItemDetails', params: { sid: itemx.idN, source: this.source }});
    window.open(itemDetailsData.href, "_blank","resizable=1");
}
else {
    const itemDetailsData = this.$router.resolve({name:'ItemDetails', params: { sid: itemx.idN, source: this.source }});
    var keepFocus = window.open(itemDetailsData.href, "_blank");
    keepFocus.blur();
    window.focus();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that opens the window?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is due to resizable=1

see working snippet below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="newWindow()">New window</button>
    <button onclick="newTab()">New Tab</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    function newWindow() {
      window.open('https://google.com', '_blank', 'resizable=1')
    }
    function newTab() {
      window.open('https://google.com', '_blank')
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Same as my comment to Pipetus, it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), you're requesting to open a popup; that's why you don't get the "tab" behavior:

> **Note**: Specifying any features in the `windowFeatures` parameter, other than `noopener` or `noreferrer`, also has the effect of requesting a popup.

I guess you should not use the `resizeable` option.

Comment: I have removed the resizable and made no difference. Got to say this is a vuejs webapp, not vanilla javascript, not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: For me to force the new window i need to put something on the features, anything, let me put noopener or noreferrer see how that behaves

Comment: In this case, not sure if its because this is a vuejs webapp, I need to put something on the features or the new window will always be a new tab. I put noopener and noreferrer as the value on the features and everything becomes a new tab and not a new window. I changed the resizable to "left=100,top=100" to force open the new window but still is not showing the tabs

Comment: If you wrote it the same way as the other `window.open` calls, and those do work, you may have a cache problem or something keeping old code. I don't see why it could keep behaving the old way if the others do work fine.

Comment: I don't think is a cache issue although it could be, and the reason i say i don't is because after i remove resizable and add the "left, top" the new window does open in those coordinates which means is reading the latest code. Thank you

Comment: @efx I missed that you added those options. I understand that adding **any** option makes it a popup, according to documentation. I suspect this is browser-specific behavior and you can't control it with JS (I mean, deciding if you open a window or a tab).